# Working with an OpenShift S2I template - How to attach to an application code?

Tags: openshift, s2i

I am very new to OpenShift and even more so to S2I.
I have an OpenShift instance (from my company) on the cloud.
And I am trying to manage a Scala project on it. My code is on BitBucket.

I noticed that there is no OOTB Scala that I can "add to project" so I located this S2I on the web:
https://github.com/OutThereLabs/s2i-scala

I connected my OC with my OpenShift cloud instance and performed the command from that site to load that s2i into my OpenShift.

Now I can add the Scala to my project. But unlike the other OOTB template options (in "add to project"; e.g. OOTB java, python, etc.) which allow me to point at some GIT where my code resides, this one does not.

Being so novice I need a direction please. Is it that this specific s2i doesn't include a source code pointer? Do I need to add it to that specific s2i to support taking my code from a different location? 
Any help / link / reference - will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own s2i build is not trivial but it is a great way to learn.

- First you need to know how the [S2I Process](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/creating_images/s2i.html) works.
- Then, you are looking for the [Git Source Input](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-code)
- Finally, you can either extend the existing [openjdk18 S2I image](https://github.com/fabric8io-images/s2i/tree/master/java/templates) or create your own one if you want to use `sbt` instead. Be aware that the assemble script will take care of cloning the repository and building the binaries. Then, the run script will be the one running the application based on the artifact generated in the previous step.